# Create an iframe with only javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have been struggling on one of those programing challenge sites for a while. It has a console type thing that lets me enter javascript and press a run button. I need to create an iframe inside of that webpage with another webpage inside of it (for example, im on thiswebsite.com/level1 and I need to create the iframe with thiswebsite.com/level2 inside of it).

Have tried creating iframes as follows:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = '<iframe src="thissite.com/level2/" height= 300 width=400>';
```

However it does not run when I try this, is there an alternative way?
Thanks.

Comment: What seems to be your issue? I copy and Pasted the Exact code into a jsfiddle (with a different source) and it worked https://jsfiddle.net/yah18c73/1/

Comment: The site simply would not run it, I assume it was looking for another solution, the answer provided below did compile and run. This is why I was stuck, because my code should have worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `createElement` method of `document`

```
var a = document.createElement('iframe');
a.src = "your path will go here"; //add your iframe path here
a.width = "1000";
a.height = "500";
document.querySelector('body').appendChild(a)
```

I just append the `iframe` to `body`. To append it to `someDiv` replace last line with below code

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the size to this? Also this answer does run, thanks.

Comment: Wc. edited the answer check. you can specify any property which is valid html attribute. I will suggest to add class name also

Comment: `a.width` and `a.height` seems to be doing that only

Answer (score 0):

I **doubt** that the site doesn't allow you to create `iframes`.

Like, if you try the below code in your `Console`

```
    //define function
    function prepareiFrame() {
        var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
        ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://google.com/");
        ifrm.style.width = "640px";
        ifrm.style.height = "480px";
        document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
    }

    //call it
    prepareiFrame()
```

Stackoverflow will throw the below error:

> Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=OoWPV7agCuHt8wf3v6egDA' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.